# Django Foreign Key relate to more than one class

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, duck-typing

I have two classes, one called `phase1` and one called `phase2`. `phase2` has an instance of `phase1` in it (as a Foreign Key relationship). Now I want to make another class, called `POObject`, that has a Foreign Key value called `purchase` to *either* a `phase1` or a `phase2` object. That is, I want to be able to create a `POObject` with `purchase` set to a `phase1` instance, and then later change it to a `phase2` instance.

I believe this is called Duck Typing, but I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do it in Django. I know Python allows for Duck Typing quite easily, but I'm guessing the Database won't allow it without at least some additional work.

Any advice on how do to this would be much appreciated.

After implementing orlenko's suggestion, I'm having trouble adding new items. Here are the views that deal with creating a new instance. The way it works is by creating a new `purchase` in `new`, and then using the instance of that `purchase` in `new2` to create a `POObject`.

```
def new(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PurchaseOrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      new_po = form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/%s' %new_po.request_number)
    else: 
      return render(request, 'input.html', {'input_type': 'Purchase Order','formset': form, 'error': True})
  else: 
    form = PurchaseOrderForm()
    return render(request, 'input.html', {'input_type': 'Purchase Order','formset': form,})

def new2(request, number):
  po=PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WorkflowForm(request.POST, initial={'purchase': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number), 'state': 'request'})
    if form.is_valid():
      new_flow = form.save()
      return HttpResponse('Good')
    else:
      print form.errors
      return render(request, 'new-workflow.html', {'form': form, 'purchase': po})
  else:
    form = WorkflowForm(initial={'purchase': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number), 'state': 'request'})
    return render(request, 'new-workflow.html', {'form': form, 'purchase': po, 'type': 'New'})
```

The appropriate form class is:

```
class WorkflowForm(ModelForm):
  purchase1=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=PurchaseOrder.objects.all(), required=False)
  purchase2=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Phase2.objects.all(), required=False)
  details = forms.CharField(required=False)

  class Meta:
    model = POObject
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Model classes are a little more restrictive than the rest of Python code, because they have to translate into actual database tables and relationships between them.

But your idea with "flexible FK" can be implemented like this:

```
class Phase1(Model):
  #...

class Phase2(Model):
  #...

class POObject(Model):
  phase1 = ForeignKey(Phase1, null=True)
  phase2 = ForeignKey(Phase2, null=True, related_name='+')

  def get_phase(self):
    if self.phase2_id: # more likely case first
       return self.phase2
    return self.phase1

  def set_phase(self, phase):
    # Detect which type it is
    if isinstance(phase, Phase2):
      self.phase2 = phase
      self.phase1 = None
    else:
      self.phase2 = None
      self.phase1 = phase

   phase = property(get_phase, set_phase)
```

Here, we have two optional FKs and use one or the other. The `phase` property hides the details, and lets you treat the two FKs as one. When you assign a Phase record to po_object.phase, the code figures out what table to point FK to.

Comment: Hm. Sounds promising. Just to clarify, if I try to create (or update) this through a form, will it automatically detect which phase to set?

Comment: Maybe you want [That](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1). But yes, if you pass a Phase1 or Phase2 instance to set_phase() in your view. it will work (see the `isinstance(phase, Phase2):`)

Comment: @lalo I had looked at GenericForeignKey, and wasn't really sure how to actually implement it.

Comment: Show us and example of your view, maybe we can help you

Comment: I don't really have a view for the functionality I want. I didn't get an error after trying something--I just knew it wasn't going to work for me to give a `POObject` a `phase2` object.

Comment: I've tried implementing orlenko's suggestion, and I'm getting the following error:

`workflow.poobject: Accessor for field 'purchase1' clashes with related field 'PurchaseOrder.poobject_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'purchase1'.` (and another one for `purchase2`, where I've used purchase instead of phase. Any idea what I need to do?

EDIT: Seems to have been fixed by adding `related_name='+'` in the definition for `purchase1` and 2

Comment: So I've Implemented your suggestion. When I try to use the get method, I get a return of None, even though there should be something there. Any ideas why?

Comment: @dar2162, could you show us the code were you set `phase` and then try to get it?

Comment: The code you posted does not explicitly set `phase` property to a Phase1 or Phase2 instance. That's a bit of functionality you have to write in your form class.

Comment: @orlenko Added the form class

Comment: Sorry, I'm posting from phone, cannot code. But what happens after you've saved the form? Does the db record have a fk value? And the property still returns none?

Comment: @orlenko. So the problem is that I want the form to be shown "as hidden" and not give the user the chance to change the Foreign Key. If I have the template render it normally (as_p), then I get the option to set it as I chose. However, there's no instance initially selected, even though I'm saying `initial={'purchase': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number)` in the view. Do I need to change that to reflect the change in the model?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, initial value gets overwritten when you submit the form.

Comment: And there's no fix for that? That's incredibly important for this application.

Comment: Wait a second, I was wrong. You initial value should be for `purchase1` or `purchase2`, as appropriate, but not for `purchase` (since the form does not know about our custom value).

Comment: Yes: I figured that out as well. Still, when I have `form = WorkflowForm(initial={'purchase1': PurchaseOrder.objects.get(pk=number), 'state': 'request'})`, there is no preselected instance.

Comment: I've figured it out! How to add a new instance, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I think Lalo's proposal is right. You can try [Django content types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Phase1(models.Model):
    #...

class Phase2(models.Model):
    #...

class POObject(models.Model):
    # Standard names.
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # Your 'generic' foreign key. 
    purchase = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then, you can do this:

```
phase1 = Phase1.objects.get(id='xyz')
phase2 = Phase2.objects.get(id='abc')
p1 = POObject(purchase=phase1)
p1.save()
p2 = POObject(purchase=phase2)
p2.save()
```

You have to include `django.contrib.contenttypes` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings (it's included by default).